# Render opaque object as background

Tags: rendering, materials

I am attempting to render 2D sprites for a game. Optional components of objects are rendered as separate sprites and layered on top. Depth sorted is created by cutting out parts of the sprite that would be occluded. Is there a material or render setting that occludes objects behind it while being invisible after rendering?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the use of Holdout material or the Holdout property of collections: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpdmneLtlXQ